# 12.04 on Mac Mini 4,1?

Tags: 12.04, mac-mini

Is Ubuntu 12.04 usable on Mac Mini 4,1 machines? The [Ubuntu Mactel support pages](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MactelSupportTeam/CommunityHelpPages) seems to be rather out of date (they list 10.04 as the latest supported, but 11.10 runs just fine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is usable on the version before. So I think it should work.
I have tried 10.04 11.10 and 12.04 on a Mac mini 3.

Comment: Any notes / useful resources, or was the entire thing without a hitch?

Answer (score 2):

I've got 32 bit Ubuntu 12.04 running on a Mini in dual boot config.  The mini is from mid 2011 or so.  Mountain Lion is on the Mac side.  I use Ubuntu to serve regions on OSGrid. I actually installed the 32 bit version by mistake and intend to upgrade it to the 64 bit version real soon now.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using it as a media centre for a while now. I could never get the Apple Trackpad or the Apple wireless keyboard working reliably. I gave up and used a Microsoft Wireless mouse and USB Keyboard. The battery on the Trackpad last like a few days and I resorted to removing the battery to maintain the charge. But as I mentioned the Microsoft Wireless Mouse works fine and has so for 3 months and still running.

The Apple wireless keyboard was iffy to activate out of resume mode so I stuck with a USB keyboard which is black and matches my Home Entertainment Centre so its near invisible.

It is very quiet so its great for watching youtube and my other media on external drives.

It's also acting as a Minecraft server and web server with no issues. It's a great little server and media centre and highly recommend it. The native OSX is just to clumsy for my needs so I'm not even dual booting.